# Logged-in users see login and signup page (django-registration)

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using the django-registration with django 1.11. Following the [docs](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/quickstart.html)
I put the URL's and works fine. But the logged users see the login page and registration page (non-sense for me).

I try `redirect_authenticated_user=True` in the URL, works for login page and not for register and crash on loggout.

**My question is :**

- I need to **get all of django-registration's URLs** and put '`redirect_authenticated_user=True`' the ones I want?
- I have to create views to see if the user is already logged in and redirect it?
- or maybe just check the template?

> obs.: I'm using only URL's and Templates od Django-registration

Comment: show your effort till now

Comment: @abi-waqas I created a [pull request](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/pull/262/commits/8d75895892f2dcaf4b5ff4242ee01ad121502cf9)

Answer (score 2):

If your registration and login page are separate routes, for the registration route, try something like this:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # redirect if user is already logged in
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
    else:
        # do signup stuff
```

If the forms are on the same page, or content for both registered and unregistered users is on the same page, you can use the same if statement as above in your templates to selectively hide/show content for signed in users:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- HTML FOR SIGNED IN USER -->
{% else %}
    <!-- HTML FOR UNREGISTERED USER -->
{% endif %}
```

And make sure for all routes that require you to be logged in, you have the `@login_required` decorator above the function.